# anaconda ImportError: No module named numpy after pip uninstall

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, anaconda, importerror, conda

I am using a ipython conda python 2.7 virtual environment.

After a suggestion of [a probable conflict between conda numpy and pip numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190757/numpy-undefined-symbol-pyfpe-jbuf), i uninstalled the "pip numpy" using `pip uninstall numpy`.

**When I try importing `numpy`, i now get the following error :**

`ImportError: No module named numpy`

If i execute `conda list` in my environment, i get

```
... [list of other packages]
numpy                     1.11.3                   py27_0
...
```

which seems to indicate that conda `numpy` package is still installed. I also can't install `numpy` using `conda install`, which says that 'All requested packages already installed.'

a print sys.path will result in

```
'', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python27.zip', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.5.1-py2.7.egg', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg'
```

Can anyone explain me why i cant use the numpy package listed in the conda packages ?

Thank you !

Comment: have you tried uninstalling the conda numpy then reinstalling using pip?

Comment: @DrBwts i did, and then numpy works fine. However this gets me back to my original problem, which is the same as the one explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190757/numpy-undefined-symbol-pyfpe-jbuf. I suspect that this is linked to the pip version of numpy, which is why i am trying to use the conda numpy instead.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
What helped for me was to force anaconda to reinstall the package with:

```
conda install numpy --force
```

Comment: This is correct, except the version, it is not required indeed. I had similar problem, having both numpy from conda and python, and after `pip uninstall numpy`, even htough `conda list` still showed both `numpy` version I could not load it. Only after `conda install numpy --force` I could (no need to specifiy version).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 64-bit python3 conda then numpy package is installed default for python3, since you are using python2 you have to do the following steps:

first open anaconda prompt
then type `conda info --envs` . 
It displays the environments installed and the
environment adjacent to which * is found is the default environment.
Activate the desired environment by typing
activate environmentname. 
After that type comment

```
conda install numpy.
```