# "ImportError" / "undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf" with pymssql

Tags: python-3.6, pymssql, undefined-symbol, zappa

I'm currently trying to launch a Lambda as a [Zappa](https://www.zappa.io/) (Python3.6). After deploying the app / configuring everything on the AWS-side, I ran the following command to test the app in my local environment,

`zappa invoke production script.main`

And got this error,

> /tmp/virtualenv_name/pymssql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined 
>   symbol: PyFPE_jbuf: ImportError
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/var/task/handler.py", line 509, in lambda_handler
>      return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
>
> File "/var/task/handler.py", line 237, in lambda_handler
>      handler = cls()
>
> File "/var/task/handler.py", line 129, in **init**
>      self.app_module = importlib.import_module(self.settings.APP_MODULE)
>
> File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in >import_module
>      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap", line 978, in _gcd_import
>
> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap", line 961, in _find_and_load
>
> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap", line 655, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
>
> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
>
> File "/tmp/virtualenv_name/script.py", line 3, in >  module
>
> import pymssql
>
> ImportError: /tmp/virtualenv_name/pymssql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: 
>   undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf

Most of the issues with `PyFPE_jbuf` that I've read about seem to involve multiple installations of a certain dependency, but none of the solutions seem to apply here. So far I've tried,

1. Un-installing and re-installing pymssql in my virtual environment, and running `zappa update`.
2. Un-installing and re-installing other packages/libraries that contain pymssql (like sqlalchemy), and running `zappa update`.
3. Un-deploying the project, doing 1 and 2, then re-deploying it.
4. Un-installing and re-installing cython in my virtual environment, and running `zappa update`.

   Is my understanding of this error correct? Any suggestions for troubleshooting? Fixes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem while trying to install `dragnet` and `spacy` in an anaconda environment. I believe `pip install` was using a cached file that was compiled using another `gcc` version. What solved my problem was uninstalling the library and then reinstalling it using the `--no-cache-dir` flag, ex. `pip install dragnet --no-cache-dir` which built the package from scratch by running the `setup.py` for the new environment.

Also note that you might need to run `sudo apt install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev` for the build to be successful (at least for `dragnet` and `spacy`, but you might need something else)

Comment: Thank you this saved me on Anaconda for the library Ta-lib as it was clashing with, I guess, a cached numpy from a diff env or py version. Uninstalling numpy and Ta-lib and then using your suggested flag to install both fixed my problem very quickly.