# I have building app in python3 with kivy it is working fine but in linux I got the error below

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy, python-3.6

> Error: ImportError:
>   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/event.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
>   undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf

I have use this method to install the Kivy:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
4. sudo apt-get install kivy-examples

I have also go through from this question: [numpy undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190757/numpy-undefined-symbol-pyfpe-jbuf)    and this also did not solve my error.

I have built the App using kivy in python3 and It is working fine. Today I have switched to ubuntu. Even when I import the kivy It is not working and shows me same error in ubuntu! Is there any solution for it? I have looked everywhere but I didn't find the issue. Thanks in Advance.

[image: Please check the ScreenShot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy undefined symbol: PyFPE\_jbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190757/numpy-undefined-symbol-pyfpe-jbuf)

Comment: You mean i have to install numpy first ?

Comment: Have you checked the answers ?, that problem is common to several libraries that use cython as kivy and numpy, try the solutions referring to cython.

Comment: Yes I have tried everything

Comment: Then you should indicate it in your question, if you do not indicate it, we will assume that you have not done it, on the other hand you should indicate how you installed kivy, the version of kivy and cython that you have installed.

Comment: okay let me edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174696/discussion-between-pardeep-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @Pardeep: I have the same problem on Xubuntu 18.04 with Kivy stable version. Install Kivy nightly build version, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy-daily`.

Comment: @ikolim Thanks sir